# Ajax Cannot Read JSON POST Data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I have a function like this:

```
function pemeliharaan(){
                    var petugas = document.getElementById('petugas').value;
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/sipetan/WebService/public/api/pemeliharaan",
                    data: "[{'id_petugas':'1','no_rek_pelanggan':'11111'}]",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                }).done(function() { 
                    alert('Pemeliharaan dikirim ke database!');
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("Input yang anda masukkan salah!");
                    var r=confirm("Ulangi?");
                    if (r)
                    {
                        window.location = "/";
                    }
                    else{};
                });
                  }
```

But, Laravel can't read my JSON data. Laravel returned:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_pegawai' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `pemeliharaan` (`id_pegawai`, `no_rek_pelanggan`, `jenis`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `catatan`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , , 2016-06-19 20:54:26, 2016-06-19 20:54:26))
```

it seems that my data (id_petugas and no_rek_pelanggan) aren't readed by that function.

I was tried change the structure of my data to : `

1. `{'id_petugas':'1','no_rek_pelanggan':'11111'}`
2. `{'id_petugas':1,'no_rek_pelanggan':11111}`
3. `[{'id_petugas':1,'no_rek_pelanggan':11111}]`
4. `[{'id_petugas':'1','no_rek_pelanggan':'11111'}]`

Still not worked. But when i try using RESTful client it work perfectly. Here is my laravel controller:

```
$Pemeliharaan=new pemeliharaan;
        $Pemeliharaan->id_pegawai=Request::input('id_petugas');
        $Pemeliharaan->no_rek_pelanggan=Request::input('no_rek_pelanggan');
        $Pemeliharaan->jenis=Request::input('jenis');
        $Pemeliharaan->latitude=Request::input('latitude');
        $Pemeliharaan->longitude=Request::input('longitude');
        $Pemeliharaan->catatan=Request::input('catatan');

        $success=$Pemeliharaan->save();

        if(!$success)
        {
            return Response::json("error saving",500);
        }    
        return Response::json("success",201);
```

**EDIT**

It also work perfectly when i used dataform to JSON on my other function:

```
jQuery('form#postPemeliharaan').bind('submit', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                var form = this;
                var json = ConvertFormToJSON(form);

                var id_pemeliharaan;
                $.each(json,function (name, value){
                   if(name=="id_pemeliharaan"){
                    id_pemeliharaan=value;
                   }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    url: "http://localhost/sipetan/WebService/public/api/pemeliharaan/"+id_pemeliharaan,
                    data: json,
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function() { 
                    alert('Pemeliharaan dikirim ke database!');
                }).fail(function() {
                    alert("Input yang anda masukkan salah!");
                    var r=confirm("Ulangi?");
                    if (r)
                    {
                        window.location = "/";
                    }
                    else{};
                });

                return true;
            });
```

**EDIT 2** (Solved my own problem):
*But i changed the contentType to form-data*

```
function pemeliharaan(){
                var petugas = document.getElementById('petugas').value;
                var json = '[{"id_petugas":1,"no_rek_pelanggan":11111}]';
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/sipetan/WebService/public/api/pemeliharaan",
                data: [{"name": "id_petugas","value": 1},{"name": "no_rek_pelanggan","value": 11111},{"name": "longitude","value": 11111},{"name": "latitude","value": 11111},{"name": "jenis","value": 1}],
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }).done(function() { 
                alert(petugas+' berhasil ditugaskan untuk melakukan pemeliharaan');
            }).fail(function() {
                alert("Input yang anda masukkan salah!");
                var r=confirm("Ulangi?");
                if (r)
                {
                    window.location = "/";
                }
                else{};
            });
              }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24497091/2159528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending invalid JSON. You can prove this by passing it through a json validator

Your single quotes should be doubles and vice-versa.

Don't manually create JSON. There are serialization methods in most languages to do it for you

Try

```
 data: JSON.stringify([{'id_petugas':'1','no_rek_pelanggan':'11111'}])
```

Comment: I have solved this problem with change type into form-data. See my edit 2. But you're the real MVP for this problem. The right one is `data: JSON.stringify({'id_petugas':1,'no_rek_pelanggan':11111})`

Comment: I was wondering why it was array but for lack of better understanding just showed how to stringify structure you had

Comment: okay. Thank you very much. Have a nice day. God bless you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if these are the only points, but I just noticed:

1. In the data set you send to Laravel there must be also the CSFR token. That's why I usually include that immediatly after the body as an hidden input and use it's value in each ajax request.
2. The correct format of your dataType property is this: {'id_petugas':1,'no_rek_pelanggan':11111}

For the rest, I would xdebug that controller to check the effective data received.

Have you also tried to intval() that ids?

```
$Pemeliharaan->id_pegawai = intval(Request::input('id_petugas'));
```

Comment: And if you use $request['id_petugas'] instead of Request::input('id_petugas')? What you have there?

Comment: when i used $request the laravel returned `Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as array`. See my edit also

Comment: What if Input::get('id_petugas') ?

Comment: i have no Input class on my laravel 5.2. Returned `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found`

Comment: add this to your controller: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Comment: still same.. i think the problem isn't my controller because it's works perfectly when using RESTClient. I think the problem is when sending the JSON