# Laravel:How to fix SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation?

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I'm trying to populate a database using seeder.

I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`forge`.`projects`, CONSTRAINT `projects_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `status_projects` (`id`))

Here are my migrations:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('subtitle');
        $table->longText('main_data');
        $table->string('budget_description');
        $table->integer('owner_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('deadline_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('city_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('website')->nullable()->default('null');  //reference
        $table->decimal('budget', 18, 4);
        $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned()->default('1');
        $table->dateTime('started_at')->nullable();
        $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned()->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

This is a migration for Status:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('status_projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
    });
}
```

Several people are working on this project, so I created an additional migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('status_id');
        $table->foreign('status_id')
            ->references('id')->on('status_projects')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Now when I try to execute the command

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get error:

> SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'status_id' (SQL: alter table `projects` add `status_id` int unsigned null)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Because when trying migrating, you have the same column in both (separate) migrations -`$table->unsignedInteger('status_id');` and `$table->integer('status_id')->unsigned()->default('1');`. Delete it in your additional migration and `php artisan migrate:refresh`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrity constraint violation: 1452 laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496935/integrity-constraint-violation-1452-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem: you have to refresh your database (ps: you are going to re-insert your rows)

```
php artisan migrate refresh
```

Comment: I don't understand, how can I avoid re-adding?

Answer (score 0):

im think your id type is TYNYINT. you must your id type change to INT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).